# After adding a variable to framework.jar it still not accessible

Tags: java, android, smali

I'm trying to modify frameworks.jar by adding a static boolean variable(just for tests)
To do it I extracted frameworks.jar from emulator decompiled it and added to LocationManager this line:

```
.field public static TEST:Z = 0x0
```

And to test this variable I created a small app where I'm trying to access to this variable using this line of code

```
sget-boolean v1, Landroid/location/LocationManager;->TEST:Z
```

But it gives me an exception.
I checked if modified framework.jar doesn't replace original by pulling it and decompiling. I found this variable in framework.jar which I pulled from phone.
If this variable exists, why it still tells me that it is not

The exception

```
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801): Process: com.greedycat.smalitest, PID: 10801
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6302)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24782)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     ... 9 more
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field TEST of type Z in class Landroid/location/LocationManager; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.location.LocationManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     at com.greedycat.smalitest.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:20)
06-30 02:16:53.388 E/AndroidRuntime(10801):     ... 11 more
06-30 02:16:53.392 W/ActivityManager( 1237):   Force finishing activity com.greedycat.smalitest/.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable name is TEST, exception mentions IS_MOCKING so    you did not recompile app properly or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I put old exception text. I already changed the name. So with this everything is ok, except it still cannot get this variable

Comment: to access private fields and methods through reflection you must set accessible flag. Can you show java code?

Comment: I changed private to public and nothing changes

Comment: `sget-boolean ` - does this command tries to read boolean variable while your variable is of type Z? Can you show real code not bytecode?

Comment: I can't show real code cuz I want to modifiy existing framework jar so I can edit and show to you only smali code.